# What controls the NIC naming convention after fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install?

Tags: ubuntu, nic, ubuntu-20.04, netplan, systemd-networkd

This is a fresh install Ubuntu server 20.04.04 system. I'm using networkd and netplan to configure networking. I did not do any custom install steps, just loaded the .iso and installed Ubuntu server through the prompts.

When these machines were shipped from the vendor, Ubuntu was already installed and the network interfaces were named `ens1f0` and `ens1f1`:

```
root@oldHost2:~# sudo lshw -C network |grep "logical name"
       logical name: ens1f0
       logical name: ens1f1
       logical name: bond0
```

However after reinstalling the OS (before running netplan) I get....

```
root@freshHost1:~# sudo lshw -C network |grep "logical name"
       logical name: ens1f0np0
       logical name: ens1f1np1
       logical name: bond0
```

Across all my sites, we use a netplan config that assumes `ens1f0` and `ens1f0`. I would like all interfaces to match this.

I know you can set the interface name with `set-name` in netplan (as defined in https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration) however you need to already match the interface somehow (using Mac address, etc) which is going to make auto-provisioning a nightmare (if not impossible). A chicken/egg scenario. I have hundreds of machines to provision and I would like to template out my netplan config without knowing the Mac addresses.

I know you can also group together the interfaces in netplan:

```
  ethernets:
    eports:
      match:
        name: ens*
```

Which may work for my case, but not all the systems have a simple two NIC setup like this so I'm not sure what the best course of action will be.

**My questions to ServerFault...**

- Since this logical name is set before Netplan is even ran, what is deciding on this name? How can I override it during OS install/provision?
- What does the `np0` and `np1` mean in the interface names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network interface naming](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067418/network-interface-naming)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider My post has two questions, and ... sort of? Doesn't answer where `np0` and `np1` are coming from and doesn't respond to if it's possible the names can be overridden before netplan is ran, which is asked in the OP.

Comment: Most likely `udev` assigns the initial names.  These can easily be overridden with rules. A good strategy might be to compare the udev rules on a vendor imaged machine to the rules installed by a generic Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @BrandonXavier Thanks for the suggestions. I'll start down that path and see what solutions I can come up with and will report back. My goal is to just have a predictable device name on all these hosts when they are provisioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is determined by systemd based on information about the device.  The name can be influenced by several different factors, including BIOS, other devices that might be installed, linux version, and driver version.  See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html for how systemd constructs the names.

For example, slot numbers may or may not be associated with PCIe slots.  I think this at least somewhat related to BIOS/ACPI, but there could be other factors.  On one of my machines, a NIC installed in one slot enumerates as enpN, and the same NIC when moved to a different slot enumerates as ensN.

I have heard of cases where PCIe bus numbers are assigned differently under certain conditions, such as the presence of a thunderbolt device during boot.  Ultimately this is probably the fault of the system BIOS for not reserving PCIe bus numbers correctly for the thunderbolt port.

As far as what you're seeing with np0 and np1, the p0 and p1 are physical port names coming from devlink `__devlink_port_phys_port_name_get`.  Presumably devlink support was added to the NIC driver, which caused the np0/np1 to appear.  If you update the older system to the same kernel version, the naming should also change.